# Check table if not empty from a list of tables in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a list of tables and check each table in the list if it is not empty (ie. must be populated). Below is the pseudo code of the logic but needs to be in TSQL.

Pseudo Code:

```
DECLARE @ctr INT = 0

// list of table objects, how to do in TSQL
DECLARE @sourceTables = {
    src.fusion_sec_assigned_workgroup,
    src.fusion_sec_user_account,
    src.fusion_sec_user_in_organisation,
    src.BULL_OHMS_WORKGROUPS,
    src.fusion_rep_extension_request_reason,
    src.fusion_rep_extension_request_trade,
    src.fusion_rep_job_ext_request_reason,
    src.fusion_rep_job_ext_request_trade,
    src.bull_rep_audit_adhoc_jobs,
    src.BULL_REP_AUDIT_JOB_NONSORS,
    src.bull_REP_AUDIT_JOB_SORS,
    src.BULL_REP_REASON_CODES
}

WHILE (@ctr < sourceTables.length)
BEGIN
    EXEC tSQLt.AssertNonEmptyTable 'sourceTables[ctr]'
    SET @ctr = @ctr + 1
END
```

EDIT: Improved attempt

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SourceTables
CREATE TABLE #SourceTables
(
    Id INT,
    TableName NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO #SourceTables
    VALUES
        (1, 'src.fusion_sec_assigned_workgroup'),
        (2, 'src.fusion_sec_user_account'),
        (3, 'src.fusion_sec_user_in_organisation'),
        (4, 'src.BULL_OHMS_WORKGROUPS'),
        (5, 'src.fusion_rep_extension_request_reason'),
        (6, 'src.fusion_rep_extension_request_trade'),
        (7, 'src.fusion_rep_job_ext_request_reason'),
        (8, 'src.fusion_rep_job_ext_request_trade'),
        (9, 'src.bull_rep_audit_adhoc_jobs'),
        (10, 'src.BULL_REP_AUDIT_JOB_NONSORS'),
        (11, 'src.bull_REP_AUDIT_JOB_SORS'),
        (12, 'src.BULL_REP_REASON_CODES')

DECLARE @ctr INT = 1
DECLARE @length INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SourceTables)
WHILE (@ctr <= @length)
BEGIN
    PRINT @ctr
    EXEC tSQLt.AssertNonEmptyTable '' -- how to refer to a table name per iteration (in C# something like SourceTables[ctr])
    SET @ctr = @ctr + 1
END
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show us your attempt

Comment: The pseudo code is my best attempt and I have the logic. I can do this fairly easily in Java, C#, and Python. I am just stumped with the TSQL syntax is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `Dynamic SQL` query. [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You did not specify the required output, I modified the `#SourceTables` to add a count column to record the no of rows in that table.

```
CREATE TABLE #SourceTables
(
    Id INT,
    TableName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    TableCount INT                   -- Added this
)
INSERT INTO #SourceTables (Id, TableName)
    VALUES
        (1, 'src.fusion_sec_assigned_workgroup'),
        (2, 'src.fusion_sec_user_account'),
        (3, 'src.fusion_sec_user_in_organisation'),
        (4, 'src.BULL_OHMS_WORKGROUPS'),
        (5, 'src.fusion_rep_extension_request_reason'),
        (6, 'src.fusion_rep_extension_request_trade'),
        (7, 'src.fusion_rep_job_ext_request_reason'),
        (8, 'src.fusion_rep_job_ext_request_trade'),
        (9, 'src.bull_rep_audit_adhoc_jobs'),
        (10, 'src.BULL_REP_AUDIT_JOB_NONSORS'),
        (11, 'src.bull_REP_AUDIT_JOB_SORS'),
        (12, 'src.BULL_REP_REASON_CODES')


DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Form the dynamic sql query
select  @SQL    = ISNULL(@SQL + ';' + char(13), '')
                + 'UPDATE #SourceTables SET TableCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + TableName + ') WHERE TableName = ''' + TableName + ''''
from    #SourceTables

-- print out for verification    
print   @SQL

-- execute the query
exec    sp_executesql @SQL

select  *
from    #SourceTables
```

Comment: Thank you, the added column is good for troubleshooting.

Comment: Question, what does `ISNULL(@sql + ';' + char(13), '')` do in particular?

Comment: initial value for `@sql` is `NULL`. Function `ISNULL()` checks for `NULL` and return the second parameter which is empty string

Comment: Any specific reason why `@SQL + ';' + char(13)` are being concatenated as first param (instead of maybe just @SQL)?

Comment: the very first time `@SQL` is null, it will be concatenate with empty string ( NULL + `;` + char(13) will still be null). Subsequent, it is not null, it is appended with `;` & carriage return `CHAR(13)`

Comment: Interesting, how is it appending all 12 `UPDATE` statements without a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Full solution including assertion with tSQLt. Basis from Squirrel.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SourceTables
    CREATE TABLE #SourceTables
    (
        Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        TableName NVARCHAR(MAX),
        TableCount INT                   -- Added this
    )
    INSERT INTO #SourceTables (TableName)
        VALUES
            ('src.fusion_sec_assigned_workgroup'),
            ('src.fusion_sec_user_account'),
            ('src.fusion_sec_user_in_organisation'),
            ('src.BULL_OHMS_WORKGROUPS'),
            ('src.fusion_rep_extension_request_reason'),
            ('src.fusion_rep_extension_request_trade'),
            ('src.fusion_rep_job_ext_request_reason'),
            ('src.fusion_rep_job_ext_request_trade'),
            ('src.bull_rep_audit_adhoc_jobs'),
            ('src.BULL_REP_AUDIT_JOB_NONSORS'),
            ('src.bull_REP_AUDIT_JOB_SORS'),
            ('src.BULL_REP_REASON_CODES')

    DECLARE @sql    NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- Form the dynamic sql query
    SELECT  @sql    = ISNULL(@sql + ';' + char(13), '')
                    + 'UPDATE #SourceTables SET TableCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + TableName + ') WHERE TableName = ''' + TableName + ''''
    FROM    #SourceTables

    -- Print out for verification    
    PRINT   @sql

    -- Execute the query
    EXEC    sp_executesql @sql

    SELECT  *
    FROM    #SourceTables

    -- Assert
    DECLARE
        @ctr INT = 1,
        @length INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SourceTables)
    WHILE (@ctr <= @length)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @tableCount INT = (SELECT TableCount FROM #SourceTables WHERE Id = @ctr)
        EXEC tSQLt.AssertNotEquals 0, @tableCount
        SET @tableCount = 0
        SET @ctr = @ctr + 1
    END
```